# That name doesn"t exist in the current context error

Tags: c#, arraylist, struct, scope

In `public static void ammount()` I get an error saying:
"The name 'mps' does not exist in the current context"
How do I fix this error?

```
   struct mp3players{

        private int ID;
        private string Make;
        private string Model;
        private int MBSize;
        private double Price;
        private int vr;

        public int id
        {
            get { return this.ID; }
            set { this.ID = value; }
        }

        public string make
        {
            get { return this.Make; }
            set { this.Make = value; }
        }

        public string model
        {
            get { return this.Model; }
            set { this.Model = value; }
        }

        public int mbsize
        {
            get { return this.MBSize; }
            set { this.MBSize = value; }
        }

        public double price
        {
            get { return this.Price; }
            set { this.Price = value; }
        }

        public int VR
        {
            get { return this.vr; }
            set { this.vr = value; }
        }

    }
   public static void mp3()
    {
        mp3players mp1 = new mp3players();
        mp1.id = 1;
        mp1.make = "GET technologies .inc";
        mp1.model = "HF 410 ";
        mp1.mbsize = 4096;
        mp1.price = 129.95;
        mp1.VR = 500;

        mp3players mp2 = new mp3players();
        mp2.id = 2;
        mp2.make = "Far & Loud";
        mp2.model = "XM 600 ";
        mp2.mbsize = 8192;
        mp2.price = 224.95;
        mp2.VR = 500;

        mp3players mp3 = new mp3players();
        mp3.id = 3;
        mp3.make = "Innotivative";
        mp3.model = "Z3 ";
        mp3.mbsize = 512;
        mp3.price = 79.95;
        mp3.VR = 500;

        mp3players mp4 = new mp3players();
        mp4.id = 4;
        mp4.make = "Resistance S.A.";
        mp4.model = "3001 ";
        mp4.mbsize = 4096;
        mp4.price = 124.95;
        mp4.VR = 500;

        mp3players mp5 = new mp3players();
        mp5.id = 5;
        mp5.make = "CBA";
        mp5.model = "NXT volume ";
        mp5.mbsize = 2048;
        mp5.price = 159.05;
        mp5.VR = 500;

       ArrayList mps = new ArrayList();
        mps.Add(mp1);
        mps.Add(mp2);
        mps.Add(mp3);
        mps.Add(mp4);
        mps.Add(mp5);

        foreach (mp3players value in mps)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ID: " + value.id);
            Console.WriteLine("Make: " + value.make);
            Console.WriteLine("Model: " + value.model);
            Console.WriteLine("MBSize: " + value.mbsize);
            Console.WriteLine("Price: " + value.price);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

**This is where the error occurs.**

I tried a couple of ways but did not find what I was searching for.

```
   public static void ammount()
    {
        foreach (mp3players value in mps)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ID: " + value.id);
            Console.WriteLine("Model: " + value.model);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

I am not very good in `C#` so an explanation what I did wrong is also very welcome!

Comment: You should show what you have tried so far. Also your title is uninformative and will not give anyone an idea what the problem is. (I did not downvote by the way as I think the question can be fixed.)

Comment: The variable **mp3** is local variable, then other function cannot access it.

Comment: @WonHyoungLee, do you mean `mps`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void ammount()
{
    foreach (mp3players value in mps)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ID: " + value.id);
        Console.WriteLine("Model: " + value.model);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

this code has knowledge of `mps`.

you would add a parameter the method so `public static void ammount()` looks like `public static void ammount(mp3players[] mps)`. that will fix this error but cause another

you will have to pass mps into the method.

Answer (score 0):

`mps` is a local variable inside `mp3()` method. It is not a global variable, so its not accessible in `ammount()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I got your point , you are getting compilation error `The name 'mps' does not exist in the current context`. So to fix this, you have to make `mps` as global variable and set that value in `mp3()` method, and use that in other methods as well.

struct mp3players
        {

```
        private int ID;
        private string Make;
        private string Model;
        private int MBSize;
        private double Price;
        private int vr;

        public int id
        {
            get { return this.ID; }
            set { this.ID = value; }
        }

        public string make
        {
            get { return this.Make; }
            set { this.Make = value; }
        }

        public string model
        {
            get { return this.Model; }
            set { this.Model = value; }
        }

        public int mbsize
        {
            get { return this.MBSize; }
            set { this.MBSize = value; }
        }

        public double price
        {
            get { return this.Price; }
            set { this.Price = value; }
        }

        public int VR
        {
            get { return this.vr; }
            set { this.vr = value; }
        }

    }
    private static ArrayList  mps;
    public static void mp3()
    {
        mp3players mp1 = new mp3players();
        mp1.id = 1;
        mp1.make = "GET technologies .inc";
        mp1.model = "HF 410 ";
        mp1.mbsize = 4096;
        mp1.price = 129.95;
        mp1.VR = 500;

        mp3players mp2 = new mp3players();
        mp2.id = 2;
        mp2.make = "Far & Loud";
        mp2.model = "XM 600 ";
        mp2.mbsize = 8192;
        mp2.price = 224.95;
        mp2.VR = 500;

        mp3players mp3 = new mp3players();
        mp3.id = 3;
        mp3.make = "Innotivative";
        mp3.model = "Z3 ";
        mp3.mbsize = 512;
        mp3.price = 79.95;
        mp3.VR = 500;

        mp3players mp4 = new mp3players();
        mp4.id = 4;
        mp4.make = "Resistance S.A.";
        mp4.model = "3001 ";
        mp4.mbsize = 4096;
        mp4.price = 124.95;
        mp4.VR = 500;

        mp3players mp5 = new mp3players();
        mp5.id = 5;
        mp5.make = "CBA";
        mp5.model = "NXT volume ";
        mp5.mbsize = 2048;
        mp5.price = 159.05;
        mp5.VR = 500;

        mps = new ArrayList();
        mps.Add(mp1);
        mps.Add(mp2);
        mps.Add(mp3);
        mps.Add(mp4);
        mps.Add(mp5);

        foreach (mp3players value in mps)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ID: " + value.id);
            Console.WriteLine("Make: " + value.make);
            Console.WriteLine("Model: " + value.model);
            Console.WriteLine("MBSize: " + value.mbsize);
            Console.WriteLine("Price: " + value.price);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    public static void ammount()
    {
        foreach (mp3players value in mps)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ID: " + value.id);
            Console.WriteLine("Model: " + value.model);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable 'mps' declared inside the function `public static void mp3()` and you are trying to access the same from another function `public static void ammount()` which can't be feasible due to the scope.

To access the 'mps' you have to remove the declaration from the `mp3()` function and move it directly uder you so defined class:

```
public class MySongColl
{
   private static ArrayList mps = new ArrayList();

    struct mp3players
    {
       ....
       .... 
    }

    public static void mp3()
    {
        ....
        ....
    }

    public static void ammount()
    {
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

**NOTE:**
*Use proper Naming convention while you write code. e.g: Speeling mistake in Function name ammount() should be amount(). And use camel case while declaring the names like struct mp3players should be Mp3Players etc. These are not necessary to build the code but essential for a developer.*